# Convergence in Probability of Random Variables -- But what Probability Measure?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

When people use the concept of convergence in probability they often just write down e.g. $X\rightarrow^p0$ to denote that $X$ converges in probability to $0$. But from what I know about convergence in probability, the concept(/definition) relies on a probability measure $\mu$:

**Definition.**
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a probability space and let $f,f_n:\Omega\longrightarrow W$ be measruable functions for every $n\in\mathbb N$. We say that $f_n$ converges in probability to $f$ if for every real $\epsilon>0$ and real $\delta>0$ there exists a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ that satisfies $n\geq N$ it holds that $$\mu\Bigg(\bigg\{\omega\in\Omega:\Vert f_n(\omega) - f(\omega)\Vert\geq\delta\bigg\}\Bigg)<\epsilon.$$

$\\$

In the example below, I have problems to find the associated measure to apply convergence in probability.

**Example.** Let $(\Omega^n,\mathcal B_{\Omega^n}, P_\theta^n)$ be a probability space where $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathcal B_{\Omega^n}$ is (canonical) Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Note that the probability measure $P_\theta^n$ depends on a parameter $\theta\in\Theta\subset\mathbb R^k$. Let $(\Theta,\mathcal B_\Theta)$ be measruable space and $\tau_n:\Omega^n\longrightarrow\Theta$ a measurable function.

$\\$
I am now concerned with the following equestions:

- Convergence in probability of $\tau_n$ to some constant $\vartheta\in\Theta$ ("Consistency of the estimator $\tau$")
- Convergence in probability of $f_n(\theta)$ to some real constant where $f_n(\theta)$ denotes the Radon-Nikodym derivative (assuming that $P_\theta^n$ is differentiable of course).

My thoughts so far (assuming the preceeding is correct):

1. Since $\tau_n$ is measurable, probabilities are well defined. But what is the probability measure? Is it the pushforward measure $P_\theta^n\circ\tau_n^{-1}$? That seems wrong though as the measure itself depends on $n$ (or does this not matter for convergence in probability?)
2. Again, due to the measurability of $f_n$ (Radon-Nikodym-derivative is measurable by definition) probabilities are well-defined. The corresponding measure space is the non-negative reals equipped with the associated Borel $\sigma$-algebra. But what is the measure used to proof convergence in probability? The pushforward measure?